# Using DDEV in WSL without being Win admin

Tags: ddev

We have a Win 11 PC used by a developer (Jhon) and administered by an IT admin (Frank).

On this PC we have WSL, on which runs Ubuntu (administered directly by Jhon), on which runs DDEV.

When Jhon creates a new DDEV project, DDEV tries to run GSUDO, for which the Windows admin password (Frank's password) is requested.

How does Frank get Jhon to do his work without being called to insert the password for every new project and without making jhon a Win 11 admin?

Is it possible to state that GSUDO may be run without Windows admin password?

I  tried
bash
sudo visudo
jhon ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/ddev

But this obviusly did not work, as it gives permissions to the user within Ubuntu, not within Windows.

I have added Jhon to docker users within Windows, but this also did not help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First: If things are configured correctly AND you're using normal FQDN (`*.ddev.site`) then you won't need Windows hosts management anyway. If you're  seeing DDEV having to edit /etc/hosts and you're not using an alternate top-level-domain or `additional_fqdns` then something is wrong with your DNS, so solve that problem first. `ping xxx.ddev.site` should resolve successfully inside WSL2. (If you can't `ping xxx.ddev.site` successfully, your DNS is broken, take a look at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/#dns-rebinding-prohibited )

However, if that's working, in this situation you'll need to avoid using the Windows side or using the /etc/hosts on the Windows side. So you'll turn off the Windows-side hosts management with `ddev config global --wsl2-no-windows-hosts-mgt`

Then you'll probably want to use a web browser inside WSL2, so install chromium or firefox inside WSL2 and use it there. It works great, and it's just like any Linux machine, and you have no need for Windows admin.

The other choice is to have your IT admin manually add entries to /etc/hosts on the Windows side.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try and I'll let you know!

Comment: Make sure you fix your networking (DNS lookup) if that's the fundamental thing. You should be able to `ping xxx.ddev.site` in WSL2. Then if you don't use fancier URLs, you don't have to think about any of this.